# Easy Double Sums Question: $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(m+n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

How to calculate $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(m+n)!} $ ?

I don't know how to approach it . Please help :)

P.S.I am new to Double Sums and am not able to find any good sources to study it , can anyone help please ?

Comment: For each $j=1,2,3,\ldots$, how many $\frac{1}{j!}$ terms are there?

Comment: Apostol's Mathematical Analysis is a good source.

Comment: Perhaps start writing the sum out for a few terms. (Note that, since this is a double sum, you'll get a 2x2 array of numbers to add.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the same as 
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}
$$
We can rearrange terms, noting that for each value of $k$ there will be terms only with 
$k > m$.  There are $k-1$ possible values of $m$ that satisfy $k>m$. So
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k!}
$$
The last trick is to note that it will be much easier to sum $\frac{k}{k!}$ so break up the numerator:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{k!} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-1)!}- \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}
$$
And this in turn is
$$
\frac{1}{0!} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-1)!} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}
= 1 +\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j!} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}
$$
So far, only rearrangement of terms has happened.  Now we note that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ is absolutely convergent, so the rearrangement of terms is valid; and the tow sums left cancel, so the answer is 
$$1
$$

Comment: Wow! You have brought it down to a single summation and solved it . Btw I have some doubts in your solution . k=m+1 , how did you make that substitution ?

Comment: Also where did n vanish to ? I know these maybe some foolish doubts , but sorry I am a novice to Double sums . Thanks

Comment: The substitution in the first line is $k=m+n$.  That is where the $n$ vanished to. And since $k=m+n$ and $n>0$, that forces $k>m$. So the $k$ sum has to start at $k=m+1$.

Comment: One last doubt sir , how did the double sum get converted to a single summation .

Comment: What I am referring to is : $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k!}$ , how come there's only one summation left now ?What about the first summation , i.e. if m ,where did it go ?

Comment: @Andy: It became the numerator in $\frac{k-1}{k!}$, because $\frac{1}{k!}$ is a term in the summation for $k-1$ of the possible $m$s.

Comment: It would perhaps be more instructive to write $\sum\frac{k-1}{k!}=\sum (\frac1{(k-1)!}-\frac1{k!})$ and then just note that the sum telescopes, instead of rearranging the entire series.

Comment: Thanks , I've got it now !

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{m,n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(m+n)!}=\sum_{h\geq 2}\frac{f(h)}{h!}$$
where:
$$ f(h)=\#\left\{(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}^2:m+n=h\right\}=h-1 $$
hence:
$$\sum_{m,n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(m+n)!}=\sum_{h\geq 2}\frac{h}{h!}-\sum_{h\geq 2}\frac{1}{h!}=\sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{1}{h!}-\sum_{h\geq 2}\frac{1}{h!}=\color{red}{1}.$$

Comment: I think a picture would help too. one with diagonal lines running through lattice points.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Under 'nice' conditions we have:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{m+n}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(k-1\right)a_{k}$$

Comment: What's the nice condition , can you specify pls ?

Comment: @Andy: A sufficient condition is that the $a_k$s are all nonnegative. Then either the two sides of the equation are equal, or both sides diverge to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Summing]

\begin{align}
&\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(m+n)!}\\
=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(1+n)!} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2+n)!} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(3+n)!} + \dots\\
=&\vphantom{+}\frac1{2!} + \frac1{3!} + \frac1{4!} + \frac1{5!} + \dots\\
 &+\frac1{3!} + \frac1{4!} + \frac1{5!} + \frac1{6!} + \dots\\
 &+\frac1{4!} + \frac1{5!} + \frac1{6!} + \frac1{7!} + \dots
\end{align}

Let's add and subtract $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{j!}$. It doesn't change the sum and it's easier to add.

\begin{align*}
=&\left(\frac1{1!}+\color{red}{\frac1{2!}}+\color{green}{\frac1{3!}}+\color{blue}{\frac1{4!}}+\dots\right.\\
&+\color{red}{\frac1{2!}}+\color{green}{\frac1{3!}}+\color{blue}{\frac1{4!}}+\frac1{5!}+\dots\\
&+\color{green}{\frac1{3!}}+\color{blue}{\frac1{4!}}+\frac1{5!}+\frac1{6!}+\dots\\
&+\color{blue}{\frac1{4!}}+\frac1{5!}+\frac1{6!}+\frac1{7!}+\dots\\
&\left.\vphantom{\frac12}+\dots\right)\\
&-\frac1{1!}-\frac1{2!}-\frac1{3!}-\frac1{4!}-\dots\\
&=\left(1+\color{red}{\frac1{1!}}+\color{green}{\frac1{2!}}+\color{blue}{\frac1{3!}}+\dots\right)-\left(\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\dots\right)=\boxed{1}
\end{align*}

Hope this helps! I know that the adding and subtracting $\sum\frac1{j!}$ came out of nowhere, but it works.

Comment: If anybody feels like replacing my picture with LaTeX, feel free to do so.

Comment: columbus8myhw: I have tried. Please, do check whether my edits correspond to what you wanted to write.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yeah, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: The motivation to add sum 1/j! makes the grid nicer to complete.